# Loading data from server with ajax, asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Can anyone help detect what I'm doing wrong... I am a beginner so I could not be more lost.

This is what I have:

Service class with this get method:

```
void OtvoriKonekciju()
    {
        uredjaj = new DBBL();
        uredjaj.entity.Connection.Open();
    }
void ZatvoriKonekciju()
    {
        uredjaj.entity.Connection.Close();
        uredjaj.entity.Dispose();
    }
public Uredjaji getUredjajPoID(int uredjajID)
    {
        OtvoriKonekciju();
        //stored procedure call
        Uredjaji list = uredjaj.entity.stp_getUredjajPoID(uredjajID).SingleOrDefault();
        ZatvoriKonekciju();
        return list;
    }
```

frmUredjaji.aspx.cs:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public Uredjaji getUredjajByID(int uid) {
    return uredjaj.getUredjajPoID(uid);
}
```

frmUredjaji.aspx:

```
$("table.dxgvTable_HDesk > tbody > tr").on("click", function () {

            // Removes any detail rows from data grid (using free version of a DevExpress dgv control)
            $("table.dxgvTable_HDesk > tbody > tr#details").remove();

            // Gets the id from hidden column (table uredjaji)
            var idnumber = $(this).find(".refIDdata").text();

            //till here is ok, i get the text whic is ID 
            //(do i need, and how, to convert it to int somehow?)

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "frmUredjaji.aspx",
                data: "{uid:idnumber}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            });

        });
        function OnSuccess(data) {
            var temp = data.d.KlijentID;
            alert("All OK, result: "+temp);

        }
        function OnError() {
            alert("Error getting data!");
        }
```

I get the column text without problems but the ajax is always returning error message specified in OnError().. 
I guess it has something to do with ajax and how i return data, well i am noob so please help

EDIT:
OK this is what I was trying to do...

When I click on a row I want to show additional data below (I want to use it on grids with many columns that cant fit into my page width. Something like a row detail that is not supported in a free version of a DevExpress data grid I am using.

Comment: change `data: "{uid:idnumber}",` to `data: {uid:idnumber},`

Comment: @rt2800
Didn't work ... thanx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka I've made it work. Its a little messy code but it works just fine hehe.
Didn't work with objects for me (couldn't figure it out) so I returned only a string with everything I wanted and it worked.

C# (if statements for fields that have NULL (else exception is thrown on NULL value)

```
static UredjajiServis uredjaj = new UredjajiServis();
static KlijentServis klijent = new KlijentServis();
static NaruciteljServis narucitelj = new NaruciteljServis();
List<Lokacije> list;
static LokacijeServis lokacije = new LokacijeServis();
[WebMethod]
    public static string ubaciUredjaj(int uid)
    {

        Uredjaji temp = uredjaj.getUredjajPoID(uid);
        string imeNarucitelja = string.Empty, prezimeNarucitelja = string.Empty, nazivKlijenta = string.Empty, nazivLokacije = string.Empty;
        int klijentID = Convert.ToInt32(temp.KlijentID);
        if (klijentID != 0)
        {
            Klijenti tempKlijent = klijent.getKlijentPoID(klijentID);
            nazivKlijenta = tempKlijent.Naziv;
        }
        else
        {
            nazivKlijenta = "&nbsp;";
        }
        int naruciteljID = Convert.ToInt32(temp.NaruciteljID);
        if (naruciteljID != 0)
        {
            Narucitelji tempNarucitelj = narucitelj.getNaruciteljPoID(naruciteljID);
            try
            {
                imeNarucitelja = tempNarucitelj.Ime;
                prezimeNarucitelja = tempNarucitelj.Prezime;
            }
            catch
            {
                naruciteljID = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            imeNarucitelja = "&nbsp;";
            prezimeNarucitelja = "&nbsp;";
        }


        int lokacijaID =Convert.ToInt32(temp.LokacijaID);
        if (lokacijaID != 0)
        {
            Lokacije tempLokacija = lokacije.getLokacijuPoID(lokacijaID);
            nazivLokacije = tempLokacija.Naziv;
        }
        else
        {
            nazivLokacije = "&nbsp;";
        }

        string msg = string.Empty;

        msg ="<div class='dwrapper'>";
        msg += "<div class='detailrow'><span class='dlabel'>Klijent: </span><span class='ddata'>" + nazivKlijenta + "</span></div>";
        msg += "<div class='detailrow'><span class='dlabel'>Naručitelj: </span><span class='ddata'>" + imeNarucitelja + " " + prezimeNarucitelja + "</span></div>";
        msg += "<div class='detailrow'><span class='dlabel'>Lokacija: </span><span class='ddata'>" + nazivLokacije + "</span></div>";
        msg += "</div>";

        return msg;
    }
```

HTML/JavaScript/jQuery

```
$("table.dxgvTable_HDesk > tbody > tr").not(':first').on("click", function () {

        $("table.dxgvTable_HDesk > tbody > tr#details").remove();
        $("td", this).css("border-bottom", "2px solid #eee !important");
        $(this).after('<tr id="details" class="dxgvDataRow_HDesk"><td colspan="20" class="dxgv"><div class="detailswrapper"><span class="dloading">Učitavanje u toku ...<span></div></td><tr>');
        var idnumber = $(this).find(".refIDdata").text();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Poslovanje/frmUredjaji.aspx/ubaciUredjaj",
            data: '{uid:"' + idnumber + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });

    });
    function OnSuccess(poruka) {
        $(".detailswrapper").html('<!--<span class="dtitle">Dodatne informacije:</span>-->' + poruka.d);
        $(".detailswrapper").fadeOut(0).fadeIn(1000);
    }
    function OnError(poruka) {
        alert("Greska pri dobavljanju informacija!");
    }
```

Thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the ajax call in this way. Hope it helps you.

Try Ajax call this way,

```
var idnumber ="dataToBeSent";`
var rawData={"uid":idnumber}; 
var finData= JSON.stringify(rawData);
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "frmUredjaji.aspx",
            data: finData,
            dataType: "json",

            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });
```

Comment: I was trying to select "anything" in specified tr td since it's a column representing ID and is only text. I wanted to pass it as ID so i can get other data connected to that id. I choose only KlijentID just for testing.

... it didn't work with this either ... I must be doing some basic stuff wrong...

Comment: Yes, I'm not clear on what data can pass and in which way and format so many mistakes on my side sorry

I want to pass a value so i can use it later in stored procedure.

Console output:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: Hmm... script is in MasterPage and I have sub folders for pages

localhost:someport/Poslovanje/frmUredjaji.aspx is Browser URL

if I change ajax URL to Poslovanje/frmUredjaji.aspx it says
'POST http://localhost:55610/Poslovanje/Poslovanje/frmUredjaji.aspx 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:4send jquery.min.js:4m.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) frmUredjaji.aspx:60m.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3r.handle'

so I think it was right the first time with just frmUredjaji.aspx

But still not working ... please be patient with me I'm so confused about everything right now thanx

Comment: If u want to know the folder structure ...

MasterPage(root)>Poslovanje(folder)>frmUredjaji.aspx
url: "/Poslovanje/frmUredjaji.aspx" and url: "frmUredjaji.aspx" returns same console output: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS` other URL changes return console output like in the comment above Which means still not working

Comment: OMG, I totally got it wrong ... in url there should be page/method but i didn't know that soooo stupid. Well my test SQL server is down but I'll try it tomorrow when I find the time and post about it

Comment: Sorry still not working ... maybe i need to enable something in webconfig or simmilar? It is so frustrating .... I created a method to return back passed string just for testing and it shows again error message. Ill become bald at the end of this.... I even turned of all addons including abp, tested in  multiple browsers still nothing